# How can I take a sample from CDF and then calculate manually chi-squared statistic?

Tags: r, design-patterns, sample, chi-squared, cdf

I have two CDFs. One of them is for my original data and another is for `rgamma`. now I should take a random sample from these CDFs and calculate the chi-squared statistic **manually** to identify p-value and GOF. I was instructed to *not* use the `chisquare` package. Here is my data:

```
x<- sort(d1)
CDFx<- ecdf(x)
d2<- rgamma(length(x),0.25436673129,0.00001157445)
y<- sort(d2)
CDFy<- ecdf(y)
```

Comment: In other words, do you want to perform a goodness-of-fit test to see if your observed data is consistent with a random sample drawn from a gamma distribution?  If so, (a) chi-squared is probably not the best test to use and (b) your question is better suited to CrossValidated...

Comment: in fact, I do not know how I can use the CDFs as frequency to calculate the chi-squre test.

Comment: Yes, Limey. I want to perform a goodness-of-fit test to see if my observed data is consistent with a random sample drawn from a gamma distribution, and I know I can use another test, but it is my professor's request and I have to do that. do you know the processes?